# iPad Mini Retina with yellow tint

Tags: ipad, hardware, screen, display

I just got a new Space Gray iPad Mini Retina 32GB Wi-fi and today I noticed that the whole screen has a yellow tint. This seems to be a common issue and I will go to an Apple Store as soon as possible to get a new one. Is there a recommended serial number or part number I should look for?

I currently have Part No. ME277KS/A and Serial No. F4KLV1G7FCM6.

Comment: Total bummer to be in that situation with a new product. It will be interesting to hear what you find out once you get to the store and can compare a few models. I wonder if what you're seeing is how they all are made, a normal variation in panel characteristics or you got an outlier that the manufacturer will exchange/repair.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother getting a replacement, get a refund as it'll likely be the same and you'll see the same issues on their demo units if you have a keen eye like I do.  Detailed reply below...

I have a space grey iPad Mini Retina 32GB WiFi/3G.  I also have the yellow tint on the lower half of the screen by the home button.  I've tried leaving it plugged in and set at 100% brightness for 4 days and the issue persists 6 weeks later.  I went into my local Apple Store and I could see that all the others on display were the same or even worse regardless if they were black or white bezels or what the serial number started with (mine is F4KM...).  It is a production issue that had been around for ages and Apple think it's now good enough for us not to notice but, a lot of us do!  It's not a glue curing issue and will not go away over time.

I've even been to the genius bar and they can't acknowledge (or refuse to) the problem even after showing them photos, a clear white screen and the greyscale test which clearly shows the issue even under the store's lighting.

I think Apple are clearly aware of this problem and just don't want to go through the expense and embarrassment of a recall affecting millions of units as only a few of us can see this widespread problem that appears to affect ALL retina iPads.  However, they will be forced to act once major magazines and consumer media start publishing these problems.

Comment: Thanks for posting specifics to back up your experience. I did edit out some of the details (like having a contract on an iPad - please document more clearly how that relates to this question if you edit that back in.)

Comment: Well said mate. I have the same problem yellow tint at the bottom. And I took it to apple store in Bristol,UK. All the Genius Bar guys did not acknowledge the problem. And they didn't even make an attempt to see and spot the issue. It really pissed me off when they do that. It clearly sounds to me that they are internally trained to not spot/acknowledge the problem. They keep saying that it's within accepted standards which is bullshit. My serial starts with F4KL..

Answer (score 1):

To the answer above. I don't think it has anything to do with the glue in the case of ipad mini/air. Reason is because the LCD screen itself isn't fused to the glass panel. If you look at ifixit.com, it clearly shows that it isn't fused. Therefore glue isn't used in ipad mini nor the ipad air.

However, it may be the case with the iphones since the LCD is fused to the glass.

I recently purchased an ipad mini with retina display (exactly one month) and till now I have not noticed any issue but then I realized my entire screen had a yellow tinge (or I could be just seeing things). Now I don't know if I should take it to the apple store and have them take a look at it, but looks of it, they probably won't do anything and I probably won't waste my time. Knowing that the replacement unit that I will get might have a different issue. I'll just have to suck it up and deal with it.

Comment: Could you expand on which answer you are referring to as answers are resorted?

Answer (score 0):

I've now been to the store and first of all, the demo units don't have any yellow tint. They opened two units and they had the yellow tint. The Apple employees also saw the tint and I will now see if the tint goes away after some usage.

The demo units serial no. started with DLXLL.

Both the person at Apple and one at another store suggested that the glue could be the issue and that it might go away after some usage. Which would make sense since the demo units are on all day.